# Does the 737 MAX's engine nacelle camber affect the pitching moment?

Tags: boeing-737, stability

A side view of the B737 MAX's engine nacelle shows a positive camber at the top. As nose camber of any lifting shape (wing or nacelle) generally allows more lift at higher AoA, do you think this feature plays a role in the nacelle destabilizing pitch up moment?

Comment: I think it's more because there's this very big engine whose thrust is not on the center-of-drag of the aircraft. The thrust is lower and forward, the drag is upper and back, it adds up to a rotary motion.

Comment: The question is not on the nacelle position effect, but on the different shape of the 737 Max nacelle vs 737 NG. A nacelle is a very low aspect ratio lifting body, able to very high AoA without stalling - and nose camber may add a lot to this point.